# Fetch xml forbiden 403 response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, axios, fetch

I am working on a project in React and I must send an XML to an endpoint, but when I do it I am getting a Forbidden 403 error. I am including the credentials and no-cors

```
 fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: (
      {'Content-Type': 'application/json;text/xml; charset=utf-8',
       "SOAPAction": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#GetVolume",
       'Accept-Language': 'en-GB',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',

       'Connection': 'Keep-alive',
       'Content-Length': Content.length                
       }),
       body: Content
    }).then(function (response) {
      toast("Procesado correctamente");
    }).catch(function (error) {
      toast("Error al procesar");
    });
```

This is the xml that I am sending

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"> <soap:Header/><soap:Body><tem:ImportarXML><!--Optional:--> <tem:pvstrDatos><![CDATA[<Importar><NombreConexion>Pruebas</NombreConexion><IdCia>1</IdCia><Usuario>auxvtamed2</Usuario><Clave>lufe3698</Clave><Datos> <Linea>000000100000001001</Linea><Linea>000000204050011001001CPV000021660000000SEELENSAF                                                             +18.00                                  00101          S2019106199    Und 000000000000001.0000000000000000000.00000000012332</Linea><Linea>000000304050011001001CPV000021660000000SEELENSAF                                                             +18.50                                  00101          S2019113899    Und 000000000000001.0000000000000000000.00000000012333</Linea><Linea>000000404050011001001CPV000021660000000SEELENSAF                                                             +19.00                                  00101          S2019107799    Und 000000000000001.0000000000000000000.00000000012334</Linea><Linea>000000504050011001001CPV000021660000000SEELENSAF                                                             +19.50                                  00101          S2019110199    Und 000000000000001.0000000000000000000.00000000012335</Linea><Linea>000000699990001001</Linea> </Datos></Importar>]]></tem:pvstrDatos> <tem:printTipoError>0</tem:printTipoError> </tem:ImportarXML></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I see you are trying to fetch result from an invalid domain.

> https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://endpoint (INVALID)

Should be

> https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/endpoint

Comment: Forbidden 403 error is an error from the Server . have you check it with Postman ?

Comment: If a remove cors-anywhere it is the error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) Url change not works